# Not able to eject again after eject react native

Tags: react-native, create-react-app

I am new to reactnative, I have successfully eject to a native build, and I found some thing to tweak after reactnative so I want to edit the js again and eject again.

But I found it not able to eject using `npm run eject` again and it shows the following error:

```
npm run eject
npm ERR! Darwin 16.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "eject"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: eject
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/xxx/work/reactnative/maoquote/npm-debug.log
```

And I checked the `package.json` in the project folder, and the `eject` block was missing, but I am sure that the `eject` block was there before I first ejection the project, seems the framework has removed it after ejection?

Don't know why reactnative not allow me to eject again, is there any way I could do that?

I am using reactnative `version 0.45`

thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created the project using `create-react-native-app` ? Unfortunately, ejecting is not reversible, you should use your version control to manual roll back.

See [`Ejecting`](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md):

> "Ejecting" is the process of setting up your own custom builds for
>   your CRNA app. It can be necessary to do if you have needs that aren't
>   covered by CRNA, but please note that aside from the use of version
>   control systems (git, hg, etc.) it is not reversible.

Comment: Thanks, using version control is a good hint, they should allow user to eject multi times though, maybe this is under development :D